# What is the most efficient way to hide element completely from your page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

**Situation**

- I have a lot of btns that I want to hide.
- I kind of get them to hide, but not exactly as I intentionally want.
- They are flashing very fast while my page is loading.
- I'm struggling trying to hide them.

**Steps I took**

- First, I used `hide()` jQuery function to do that. I liked it, but then
  I notice all those btns is flashing during page load. #Curious ???
- Second, I learned that 
  `.css("display","none");` is faster than `hide()` so I tried that, and I still get the same result, maybe it faster, but I still see the flashing.
- Third, some people claim that `.attr('disabled', true);` is even faster, and **YES** I've tried that, and that is not even working at all.
- `.attr('disabled', true);` might be outdated, then I use the most current one `.prop('disabled', true);` , and that still still not working !

I'm completely clueless now. I hope someone can help me put an end to this.

What is the most efficient way to hide element completely from your page ?

Comment: By hiding you mean like its not even exists? To make the page loading faster ?

Comment: You can add the display none to the buttons without using javascript. Is there a reason you need to use js?

Comment: Could we see an example? You really aren't suppose to use JQuery were css is supposed to go. Meaning that If you knew you needed to hide the items at page load why not use css to do so?

Comment: @druidicwyrm: Please correct me, if I am wrong. I am new to all of these. I use jQuery `hide()` because I want to be able to show them back at one point. I not even sure which way is better, as long as I can trigger to show them back, I am happy. Please advise.

Comment: @bassxzero : Can I still show them, if I use css ? Is there a way to stop/prevent the flashing in the beginning ?

Comment: @rangerover.js  "is roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "none" )" http://api.jquery.com/hide/ . So yes set display none with css then call .show(); with JQuery.

Comment: Thank-you guys so much for all your effort. I will go a head and do that now.

Comment: most effiecient is setting one container class and thus using the C++-stored CSS rules to turn a whole arbitrary collection of elements hidden or visible. that's MUCH faster than looping in JS and manipulating the DOM for each element affected. using CSS also avoids the annoying page load flashing because the CSS will be applied before the HTML is shown, whereas JS would need to load jquery, then run all the code, all after the page was already visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delay you are observing is the time it takes the browser to download and execute the script, the method in JavaScript you use to set `display:none` on the buttons doesn't matter, there will always be a delay (because the browser has to download, parse and execute the script).

The **fastest** way is to not use JavaScript and simply set `display: none` on the buttons via CSS (inline, or in a stylesheet) when the page is rendered.

Comment: +1 Thanks for tip, I will definite try that. If I use inline css, can I still show them back at some point if I want to. I hope you don't mind elaborate that.

Comment: @rangerover.js - yes, toggle a class on the element (like `show-i` and in your CSS add the rule: `.show-i { display: block !important; }`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `hide()` and `.css('display', 'none')` are virtually equivalent. The flash is occurring because of the time it takes to download and execute the script after the page's initial load.

The fastest way, of course, to hide the buttons is to remove them from the HTML markup altogether. :)

Assuming, however, that you don't want to remove the buttons from the markup and that instead perhaps at some point you will want to show the buttons programmatically, you will want to hide them with CSS from the outset:

```
button {
  display: none;
}
```

(The `disabled` attribute simply makes it so that the user cannot interact with the button on browsers that support that attribute. It does *not* hide the element.)

Comment: Thanks for straight forward explanation, and tip.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in html5, there is a new `hidden` attribute that controls whether an element is shown or not. You should probably add this to the elements. That way, the elements are hidden at the same time the html is parsed, and there is no delay.

You can also add this the standard way with jquery, by using `$(element).attr("hidden", "true");`

However, if you add the attribute with jquery, the delay will still be there, as there will be a delay between when the html is shown and when the js is loaded and run.

Note: this only works in IE 11+

Comment: This is new, never heard of that. Can I do that using jQuery ? Can you add that as part of your answer. People might like your solution later on.